# iPhone - update the property of nth object of a NSMutablearray from touchesMovedwithEvent

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my earlier post in [iPhone - update the property of nth object of a NSMutablearray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6017555/540144) i got something that worked in viewDidLoad but when i am trying to use almost the same code in -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event then the application crashes.

@interface

```
int activeItem;
int startFrom;
NSMutableArray *iconsMutableArray;
NSMutableArray *textsMutableArray;
```

and then

```
@property int activeItem;
@property int startFrom;
- (NSMutableArray *)iconsMutableArray;
- (NSMutableArray *)textsMutableArray;


@synthesize activeItem;
@synthesize startFrom;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{    
    activeItem = (int)startFrom + (int)round(animationEndTo/AngleForEachItem);  
    [[iconsMutableArray objectAtIndex:activeItem] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Guide-Icon-%d_Active.png", activeItem]]];
}
```

But my application fails to update the UIIMageView and crashes without showing any error message.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Below is the crash report:

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000032200002
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: objectAtIndex:
iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3 (iPad/8F192)
iPhone Simulator 238.2, iPhone OS 4.3 (iPad/8F192)

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0197a09f objc_msgSend + 19
1   ???                             0x00229810 OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNumber + 0
2   UIKit                           0x003b90f4 forwardMethod2 + 92
3   UIKit                           0x003b90f4 forwardMethod2 + 92
4   UIKit                           0x0030fd97 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 481
5   UIKit                           0x002f0c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
6   UIKit                           0x002f5f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
7   GraphicsServices                0x01e87992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
8   CoreFoundation                  0x017f5944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
9   CoreFoundation                  0x01755cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
10  CoreFoundation                  0x01752f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
11  CoreFoundation                  0x01752840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
12  CoreFoundation                  0x01752761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
13  GraphicsServices                0x01e861c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
14  GraphicsServices                0x01e86289 GSEventRun + 115
15  UIKit                           0x002f9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
16  MJA                             0x00002bde main + 96 (main.m:14)
17  MJA                             0x00002b75 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9119d922 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch_sim.dylib           0x01d92f36 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 237
2   libdispatch_sim.dylib           0x01d93333 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 162
3   libdispatch_sim.dylib           0x01d93593 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 261
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9119cd21 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9119cb66 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:  WebThread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9117709a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x91177807 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x017f5d86 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x01752e74 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x01752840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x01752761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
6   WebCore                         0x02f13913 RunWebThread(void*) + 499
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a47fd _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a4682 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9117709a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x91177807 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x017f5d86 **CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x01752e74 __CFRunLoopRun + 708
4   CoreFoundation                  0x01752840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
5   CoreFoundation                  0x01752761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
6   Foundation                      0x0008b102 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 398
7   Foundation                      0x00055cf4 -[NSThread main] + 81
8   Foundation                      0x00055c80 __NSThread__main** + 1387
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a47fd _pthread_start + 345
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a4682 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x91196066 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   CoreFoundation                  0x017872bc __CFSocketManager + 812
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a47fd _pthread_start + 345
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x911a4682 thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x05e0e840  ebx: 0x05a0ef11  ecx: 0x05a05484  edx: 0x05e6b200
  edi: 0x32200002  esi: 0x00229810  ebp: 0xbfffd728  esp: 0xbfffd6c4
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x0197a09f   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x32200002

Comment: hi Jhaliya,
I have added the crash report. Please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice this at the top of your crash log;

> Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
>   0x0000000032200002 Crashed Thread: 0
>   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Any time you see `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` your first thought should be 'I've over released some object'.

As @csch said, you should turn on zombies and see what info that tells you.

My guess is that `iconsMutableArray` is initialized via a slice of code like this;

```
iconsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

which assigns but does not retain (read the memory management guide [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)).

Also you should be using gesture recognizers instead of implementing the touch handling yourself. Read about that [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Comment: Thanks Bill,
I have solved by changing the declaration like:

 iconsMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];

Comment: No, that is not the best fix. Please read the docs I linked to. While you are no longer crashing with that line of code, you are leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `iconsMutableArray` got released somewhere, or was never set.  Maybe you set it to an autoreleased object and forgot to `retain` it?

Comment: hmm i forgot to retain that, actually i didn't know that :p

Answer (score 0):

I recommend rewriting the code in multiple lines and then step through with the debugger to see if either the image or the array is nil. It's also possible that you are accessing an index that is out of bounds.

Also set NSZombieEnabled to YES as described [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled). This might give you are more detailed error message.